# Grab content of a text file and set part of the text file into different variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on creating a batch file and having a hard time trying to extract content of a text file to different variables.

As an example, I have Input.txt (the content is exactly what I have in my actual text file).

And I would like to exact what is in the brackets to different variables. (ex. var_1, var_2)

I'm having a hard time because the servers have "AS" in their names and I want to be careful not to remove them from the output.

Would someone provide assistance with this?

**Input.txt**

```
    Indexing SERVER_HOSTS as (SERVERAS01 SERVERAS02 SERVERAS03)
    Indexing SERVER_ROOT_PATHS_LIST as (I:\tmp I:\tmp I:\tmp)
```

**What I would like to set my variables to:**

```
var_1=SERVERAS01 SERVERAS02 SERVERAS03
var_2=I:\tmp I:\tmp I:\tmp
```

Comment: The `FOR` command with the `/F` option allows you to read a text file.  It also has a `DELIMS` option to break up the line into multiple `TOKENS`.  But since you want to assign each line to a new variable you will need to increment a counter variable to do so.  The `SET` command with the `/A` option will allow you to increment a variable for each line that is processed by the `FOR` command.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of Squashman, you can do something like that :

```
@echo off
If "%~x1" neq ".txt" (
    Goto :Help
)

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('Type %1') do (
    Set /a Count+=1
    Set "VAR[!Count!]=%%a"
)

Cls & color 0B
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    Set VAR_%%i=!VAR[%%i]!
)

echo VAR_1=%VAR_1%
echo VAR_2=%VAR_2%

Pause & Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Help
Color 0C & Mode 90,3
echo(
echo       Usage : Drag and Drop a .txt file over this script:"%~nx0"  
Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where should I add ENDLOCAL and how should I be assigning a variable?
I ultimately want to assign what is in VAR_1 and VAR_2 to to a variable. @Hackoo
So:
VAR_1_1=%VAR_1%
VAR_2_1=%VAR_2%

Comment: @casao01, let's not delve into scope creep.  You defined a question and you were given and answer that solved your question.  Normally questions without code attempts are closed immediately.   I would accept this as an answer to your question and play around with the code you were given to make it do anything else you need it to do. We are not here to teach you how to code from scratch,.